# Manipulating Indices in an ofMesh object

Tags: c++, mesh, openframeworks, indices

Still figuring out how to use `ofMesh` properly, my goal right now is to have a point cloud, have randomly connected points (using indices), and be able to shuffle the indices on click. I was pointed in the direction of using a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but that won't work until I have indices figured out.

Currently I am creating the mesh by just adding vertices with random coordinates, but not explicitly defining any indices. When I use `ofSetupIndicesAuto()`, it connects the indices too orderly, and `ofClearIndices()` isn't doing anything unless I actually setup the indices in *some* way.

Something I don't understand is how the vertices are connected when I am not explicitly defining indices for them. I assumed indices are set up automatically in the order of the vertices, but I guess not.

Here is the shuffle I'm trying to perform on the indices (placed in `ofApp::mousePressed()`):

```
    for (int i = numVerts - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
        int index = (int)ofRandom(i);
        int tempIndex = mesh.getIndex(index);
        mesh.setIndex(index, mesh.getIndex(i));
        mesh.setIndex(i, tempIndex);
    }
```

Comment: I found that using setupIndicesAuto() in the foreach that creates my vertices works to define indices on start up. What I can't seem to get now is the Fisher Yates Shuffle..., it returns no error and doesn't set any new indices. Edited original post to show the snippet for the shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shuffled vector to set the indices. For example:

```
vector<int> indices(numVerts);
// Init indices vector
int acc = 0;
for(vector<int>::iterator it = indices.begin(); it != indices.end(); ++it){
    *it = acc;
    ++acc;
}
// Shuffle
random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end());
// Update indices for the mesh
mesh.clearIndices();
mesh.addIndices(indices);
```

You can see [here](http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/graphics/generativemesh.html) how indices work. Basically they help you to tell the graphic card how to connect the vertices of your `ofMesh`.